# How to use Python to modify the active item in the outliner?

Tags: python, outliner

I would like to invoke the `REMAP` operation within the `outliner.id_operation` from another context, however, the `id_operation` only recognizes selected objects within the outliner.

How can I use Python to modify the active item in the outliner?

[image]

The code is as follows：

```
import bpy


# set override obj
obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
override = bpy.context.copy()
override["id"] = obj
override["selected_ids"] = [obj]

# set override areas and regions
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == "OUTLINER":
        override["area"] = area
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == "WINDOW":
                override["region"] = region

# run id_operation
with bpy.context.temp_override(**override):
    bpy.ops.outliner.id_operation(type="REMAP")
```

I would like to implement a data management viewing feature, and during the viewing process, I want to directly facilitate Remapping of Users. The official UI for this function is excellent, and I wish to directly adopt it in my implementation.

The intended functionality would roughly resemble the following, but due to this issue, there is a mismatch between the Remap Users objects and what my UI currently targets. The feature remains incomplete because of this problem.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get `bpy.ops.outliner.id_operation(type="REMAP")`? When I checked on Blender 4.0, the operator is `bpy.ops.outliner.id_remap(id_type='MATERIAL', old_id='<old-material-name>', new_id='<new-material-name>')`

Comment: This is [xy-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please explain what you are trying to accomplish? Like swap materials of objects? Can you give an example?

Comment: [API link](https://docs.blender.org/api/4.0/bpy.ops.outliner.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.2#bpy.ops.outliner.id_operation).

I would like to implement a data management viewing feature, and during the viewing process, I want to directly facilitate Remapping of Users. The official UI for this function is excellent, and I wish to directly adopt it in my implementation.

Comment: "Data management viewing feature" :D It would be more useful to just plainly say, what you want to see and where and also what you want to do with it.  Outliner is not very Python friendly unfortunately. But you can change relationships between data-blocks easily, so I think it should be easy to get good help here if it was possible to manage the amount of vagueness implementation in the inquiry formulation process.  ;) I think you should edit the question and provide specific details and context about what you are trying to do.